# Get document ID for the template - Orbeon

Tags: forms, templates, metadata, orbeon

I want to get the meta data from the template form. On the template form we have set meta data for some fields. We need this meta data to create a object which contains both the meta data, and the data that has been filled out, and create an object that contains these data.

When a user fill out a form, we only get the data a user has filled out. How can we achieve the meta data from the template.

In our database, I can see both the template and the filled out form have an unique ID, how can I pass this ID for the template, so I will receive it when the user has filled out the form, so I can look up the template form, and get the meta data?

Is there a way to get the ID for which template has been filled out? or can I pass the ID with the XML file, containing the filled out form?

The webservice is in grails (JAVA).

Best Regards
Daniel Knudsen

Comment: I found out that the meta data is also sent with the filled form. So I dont have any need for help to this anyway.

Comment: Good to hear, sorry for not checking this earlier.